# VMWare: Can't copy text from Ubuntu 12.04 guest to Windows7 host

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-12.04

I've got Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) running as a guest under VMWare 8.0.4 build-744019. The host is Windows7 sp1 (64-bit).

I can copy text from Ubuntu into Windows, but not back. VMWare tools is installed and clipboard sharing is enabled (otherwise I wouldn't be able to copy from the guest to host) but something seems to be broken. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here, no resolution... I don't have a VMware support contract anymore (expired) so I just live with it :/ Didn't used to be this way, they must've broken something. You running VMware 8.x latest stable too?

Comment: Yes. This is the latest update at the time of this writing.

Comment: You could try asking in the VMware Community forums; they usually have staff on-hand to field questions such as this. Or better yet, if you have a support contract that's still valid, ask them directly and they WILL get back to you with a resolution. Since VMware is proprietary software, I don't think there's a whole lot we can do right now short of complain to them. This is more of a defect in the software rather than something that we can grab onto and fix.

Comment: Okay, I've posted the question on their forums: http://communities.vmware.com/message/2075452#2075452